# Facebook publish_actions no longer working in desktop app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

According to this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog
All new apps after April 30,2014 now require approval to use publish_actions. I have a desktop application that posts to user's facebook walls.  The users used to be able to create their own apps buy simply naming it, adding their contact email, setting it to a desktop app and taking it out of sandbox mode.  Now, it seems they will need to submit their apps for approval in order to post.  The problem is the approval submission requires a platform selection.  The FB app doesn't use any of the platforms listed.  It's not a mobile app and it's not a website.  The app is merely a way for desktop users to post to their wall once they log in.  So what needs to be done in order to get new apps approved for this?

Comment: What is the question here mate? You need your app to be approved by Facebook, develop it in sandmode then fill their online tiring application, with a hope they will give you the publish_actions permit

Comment: were you able to solve your problem. select an answer as correct or post your own

Answer (score 0):

Here you go https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review?locale=en_GB

> Desktop apps should submit a Web platform and include detailed screenshots or a screencast of the integration.